# US visa DS160, previous visa same country but different location

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I am applying for a B1/B2 US visa and filling out the DS160 form. I had a US visa before, but am unsure about the following question regarding my previous visa:

"Are you applying in the same country or location where the visa above was issued, and is this country or location your place of principal of residence?"

I will be applying in the same country, but in a different location. The country is my country of residence, but I do not live in the location where I am planning to apply for the visa (the visa center in my city does not accept B1/B2 applications anymore, so I had to find a different one).

This is a yes or no question, but I do not know what to select. Any suggestions?

Comment: My (wild) guess is that they use "country or location" to avoid issues with China who strenuously object to Hong Kong, Macao or Taiwan being other "countries", so they are other "locations", but they mean "country". The text says "OR" anyhow, so if you are in the same country and it is your place of principal residence it should be find to answer Yes. Let's see if someone else has a better answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with jcaron on this one.  I assume that the previous visa was issued through the "visa center in your city" that no longer handles B visas.  In that case, the answers are:

> Are you applying in the same country or location where the visa above was issued

Yes.  You should answer yes if the country is the same or if the location is the same. You're applying in the same country.

> and is this country or location your place of principal of residence?

Yes, the country where you're applying is the country where you principally reside.

Thus, the answer should be yes.

Comment: your assumption is correct. Thanks!